# How do I do this type of 2D "fancy" indexing without python loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a 2D array to be sampled and a 2D array of indices (axis 1 of the index array is aligned with source and destination axis 1, and axis 0 of the index array is aligned with the destination axis 0 and contains indices of the source array)  How can I produce a destination array without iterating over one of the two axes?

Want to replicate this result without python iterations:

```
wid = 10
hig = 5
ix_ct = 2

src = np.arange(wid*hig, dtype=float).reshape((hig, wid))
dst = np.empty((ix_ct, wid), dtype=float)
ix = np.random.random_integers(0, hig-1, (ix_ct, wid))

for i in range(ix.shape[1]):
    j = ix[:,i]
    dst[:,i] = src[j,i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to give `src` a 2nd indexing array that matches (broadcasting wise) `ix`:

```
src[ix,np.arange(ix.shape[1])]
```

e.g.

```
array([[ 40.,  31.,  42.,  23.,  34.,  25.,   6.,  37.,  18.,   9.],
   [ 40.,  21.,  12.,  43.,   4.,  25.,  46.,  17.,  38.,  29.]])
```

---

To explain, think of a 2d index array, `iy`, same shape as `ix`, but with the `i` values from your iteration:

```
In [72]: iy=np.array([np.arange(10),np.arange(10)])
In [75]: iy
Out[75]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [76]: src[ix,iy]
Out[76]: 
array([[ 40.,  31.,  42.,  23.,  34.,  25.,   6.,  37.,  18.,   9.],
       [ 40.,  21.,  12.,  43.,   4.,  25.,  46.,  17.,  38.,  29.]])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing
docs for interger array 'advanced' indexing

Comment: Whoa.   I'm having trouble understanding how numpy is interpreting this.  But it works!

Answer (score 0):

Simply index appropriately. Create a matrix i with the same size as ix and the desired behaviour for the second index, and numpy will handle it correctly.

```
import numpy as np

wid = 10
hig = 5
ix_ct = 2

src = np.arange(wid*hig, dtype=float).reshape((hig, wid))
dst = np.empty((ix_ct, wid), dtype=float)
ix = np.random.random_integers(0, hig-1, (ix_ct, wid))

# old
for i in range(ix.shape[1]):
    j = ix[:,i]
    dst[:,i] = src[j,i]

# new
i = np.tile(np.arange(ix.shape[1]),(ix.shape[0],1))
dst2 = src[ix,i]

print dst
print dst2
```